# How can I show an "&" (ampersand) in button or label text?

Tags: vb.net, windows, ms-access

I would like to show the `&` character, *not* the keyboard shortcut in the text property of a button or label.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If you are trying to display `&` in button text, use `&&`. A single `&` is used for keyboard shortcuts, and a double ampersand will escape that.

The article *[Escape ampersand (&) character in C#](https://web.archive.org/web/20160317212020/http://moiashvin-tech.blogspot.com/2008/05/escape-ampersand-character-in-c.html)* mentions that you can leave the caption unaltered with single `&` and just set `UseMnemonic` property of the button  to `false`.

Comment: "Gets or sets a value indicating whether the control interprets an ampersand character (&) in the control's Text property to be an access key prefix character." This property also exists for labels.

Comment: Is there a way to set a groupbox, for example, to UseMnemonic = false?
They don't seem to have that property.

I just hate how hacky it feels to have those shortcuts lying around everywhere

Comment: On some others controls like **TabPage** or **TrayIcon** you need to triple escape the amperstand (`&`) character using `&&&`

Answer (score 6):

Try double `&` (`&&`). It works with VBA code.

Comment: VBA is not VB.net, although in this case it's the same. The VBA question is [vba - How to put an ampersand in a header/footer in Excel? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23129359/how-to-put-an-ampersand-in-a-header-footer-in-excel)