# How to put an ampersand in a header/footer in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a header which needs an ampersand to separate two words.

`Hello & World`

But it ignores the `&` because most of the built in *functions* evaluate it to a value ie.

`Page &[Page] of &[Pages]` => *`Page 1 of 3`*

`&[Time]` or `&T` => *`10:26`*

So, how to escape an ampersand in a header?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out to be a super simple solution ...

Double the `&&` to escape from Excel trying to evaluate to a built-in function.

Same in VBA String for: *hello & world*

`Sheet1.PageSetup.CenterHeader = "hello && world!"`

Comment: Also applies to VB6 and VB.NET strings