# Ampersand (&) error with .Find

Tags: vba, outlook, ampersand

I have created a program that searches through my outlook emails for a specific subject line. It works great, however I receive an error whenever one of my strings to search for contains an "&" symbol in it. Here is a sample of the code I'm working with.

```
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNs As Namespace
Dim olFldr As MAPIFolder
Dim olMi As MailItem
Dim olItms As Items

Dim subj As String

Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set olItms = olFldr.Items

subj = "Life&Health Insurance"

Set olMi = olItms.Find("[Subject] = " & subj)
```

I get a "condition is not valid" error when it runs into anything with an ampersand. Please help.

Comment: My guess is it's the same as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23129359/how-to-put-an-ampersand-in-a-header-footer-in-excel) - double the ampersand.

Comment: Also, `olItms` is `Dim`med but not initialized in the code sample

Comment: Thanks for the input Joe. Unfortunately I tried that and still have the issue. Thanks you Orphid, I will add it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to declare a string variable using the Chr(38) statement:

```
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNs As Namespace
Dim olFldr As MAPIFolder
Dim olMi As MailItem
Dim olItms As Items
Dim subj As String

Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set olItms = olFldr.Items
Set subj = "Life" & Chr(38) & "Health Insurance"

Set olMi = olItms.Find("[Subject] = " & Chr(34) & subj & Chr(34))
```

Also when filtering text fields, you can use either a pair of single quotes (') or a pair of double quotes (") to delimit the values that are part of the filter. See the [Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869662.aspx) method of the Items class described in MSDN.

Comment: Did you try to debug the code? What error do you get?

Comment: Awesome! That did it! Yeah I was looking at the .Find method in MSDN and I wasn't having much luck. So I guess I use Ch(34) for the quotation mark. But yeah, That made it work. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Ken : you should now "Accept" this answer by clicking the checkamrk on the left.